# How to create task in ConEmu that opens two tabs, goes to specific directory and runs tasks?

Tags: command-line, powershell, console, conemu

Through ConEmu, I'm trying to create a task that will open up two tabs, go to a specific directory, and execute two different commands.  Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
cmd -cur_console:n:d:"C:\SourceControl\Admin\Admin":t:"Admin" /c gulp watch

powershell.exe -cur_console:s1TVnd:"C:\SourceControl\Admin\Admin":t:"Admin 2" /c ".\server.ps1"
```

How can I accomplish what I'd like to do - go to the above directory and run the two commands in two separate command prompts?